# What is the right way to add a sum to a table in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sum

I'm displaying a list of `items` which have a `price`attribute in an HTML table.

What is the right way of getting the total `price` add the end of the table (and where should the calculation happen)?

I can think of 3 obvious ways, but I don't know which one is the most "orthodoxic"

1- in the controller

```
@items = Item.all
@item_total = @items.sum(:price)
```

and I simply display `@item_total`in my last line

2- in the view, on the last line

```
<%= @items.sum(:price) %>
```

But I'm not sure that it's OK to do this in a view (it works, but is it OK?)

3- in the view, add this on the last line

```
<%= @items.inject(0){|s, e| s + e.price} %>
```

But this doesn't feel right to add this kind of logic in the view.

So which one of these is the right one? Or is there another way I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way

```
# In your controller write
@item_total = Item.sum(:price)
```

and `@item_total` use in your `view` file

**Update**

If you use this like `index` action then you can do this way

```
@items = Item.all
@item_total = @items.sum(:price)
```

but if you want to only `item_total` then don't pass two queries for sum you can do like

```
@item_total = Item.sum(:price)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use first option, as view should contain least code. 
Hence use your code in controller only.

Answer (score 1):

```ruby
@items = Item.all
# this is Array#sum, calculation is done in Ruby. usually slow
@items.sum(:price)
```

whereas

```
# this is Relation#sum -> does a calculation at DB. usually faster
Item.scoped.sum(:price) # OR Item.sum(:price)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is always desirable to reduce the number of queries that are required to fetch the data from the DB....
You have two options to fetch your data...

@items = Item.all
@item_total = @items.sum(:price)

This would not run as there should be &:price instead of :price...more over if this style of code is now being discouraged due to the non support for the ARel...

Therefore, according to me the code that you should use

@items = Item.scoped
@item_total = @items.pluck(:price).sum(:price)

The benefit is that the @item is an ARel object and can be used in the further calculations...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
Sum Dolars: <%= @customer_reports.sum(&:mount) %>
```

Comment: Please fix your post with good SO code (missing a blank space)